# Created a new domain and S3, it resolves with www but not without www

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, dns

I have a domain registered with GoDaddy. Domain is : [www.dnareversecomplement.com](http://www.dnareversecomplement.com)
DNS points to AWS (using Route 53)

Created content for it in S3 - connected bucket to domain as required. Name of bucket is [www.dnareversecomplement.com](http://www.dnareversecomplement.com)
Content uploaded, and I can view the domain here:

http://www.dnareversecomplement.com/

Created a second S3 bucket called dnareversecomplement.com and pointed it to the first bucket: [www.dnareversecomplement.com](http://www.dnareversecomplement.com)

All looks good, but when I browse to :
http://dnareversecomplement.com

It doesn't work. I can't get to the domain unless I use www.

What am I doing wrong please?

Answer (score 0):

1- In  CloudFront distribution, you need to set Alternate Domain Names (CNAMEs) to the root domain and www subdomain. In your case, these are dnareversecomplement.com and [www.dnareversecomplement.com](http://www.dnareversecomplement.com).

2- Create two A records (one for dnareversecomplement.com, and the second for [www.dnareversecomplement.com](http://www.dnareversecomplement.com)) in your DNS zone to point CloudFront distribution.

Please see the following example: [link](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/userguide/website-hosting-cloudfront-walkthrough.html)

Comment: I thought I could do this with just Route53? Which is what I have read in most of the tutorials. Is that not possible.

Answer (score 0):

you need to create a redirect from your second bucket to your main domain. you can read more [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/userguide/how-to-page-redirect.html#redirect-endpoint-host)